# Issues with Symfony/Propel and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, propel, vagrant

I am attempting to to use Symfony2 with Propel ORM to generate SQL to be run on a MySQL database. The DB is running on a VM on port 3306. 3306 is forwarded by virtualbox to the VM so the database is accessible externally. Symfony2 is running on Apache, which is also located inside the VM.

When I attempt to generate the model classes using:

```
php app/console propel:build
```

everything works fine and the classes are usable in my project. However, when I attempt to generate the SQL using:

```
php app/console propel:sql:insert --force
```

I get an error saying:

> Next exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away' in [REDACTED]/propel1/generator/lib/util/PropelSqlManager.php:259 Stack trace:

Followed by a stack trace.

I checked the config and parameters YML files and everything is correct. When I test connecting with pure PHP, using the exact same credentials, everything works just fine and I am able to execute SQL against the database.

Any thoughts as to what may be causing this? I feel like it may have to do with improper characters in yml because my password contains hash symbols (#).

Comment: Any chance you can try a password with no `#` to exclude this possibility?

Comment: @cheesemacfly Ended up creating a new user just for propel with all privileges but I still get the error `Next exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away' in [REDACTED]/propel1/generator/lib/util/PropelSqlManager.php:259
Stack trace:` followed by a stack trace. It still appears to work with pure PHP. I should add that I turned on general logging and it appears that propel was not even executing any queries against the DB.

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens due to low resources of your Virtual Machine. Such error occurs usually on a timeout.

You can try increase these timeouts in your `php.ini`:

```
mysql.connect_timeout = 300
default_socket_timeout = 300
```

Comment: Well, this wan't the solution, but your comment gave me an idea. I was trying to run the console commands outside the VM, assuming it would work because the port was forwarding. Trying the same thing inside the VM, everything works fine. Stupidity on my part, I think. Thanks for the help anyways!